# Recordings for a Kinect for Windows v2

Tags: kinect, kinect.toolbox

I'm searching for some recordings that I can use in Kinect Studio. Is there some platform where people share this recordings?

An alternative would be an Kinect Simulator but I can't find one that is willing to work with Kinect Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Search for xed files through Google (filetype:xed)

You can refine your search "filetype:xed kinect" for example

Hope that helps